# Is there any condition that large amount of object from sinker class?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In the case, it creates about 30000 instances of sinker class, is there some reason? The parallelism of sinker is 16.

code as:

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.addSource(new Source).addSink(new Sinker)
env.execute()



class Sinker extends RichSinkFunction[String]{
    lazy val connection = ...

    override def invoke(value: String, context:SinkFunction.Context[_]): Unit = {
        connection.get
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it creates 30000+ instances of sinker class?

Comment: @bupt_ljy, from connection count, it could be found at some server like redis server.